# How can I import a table in MATLAB with footer rows?

Tags: matlab, text-files, footer, data-import

I have a text file with header lines above the table and below the table is a blank line and then a table with summary statistics for the table.  Handling the header lines is easy as most of the standard functions have an option for that (i.e. readtable).  The length of the file is not always the same.  The issue with `readtable` is that the footer table has fewer columns than the main table, so the function is unable to read those lines and returns an error.

This is the error that I get with `readtable`:

```
Error using readtable (line 216)
Reading failed at line 2285. All lines of a text file must have the same number of delimiters. Line 2285 has 0 delimiters, while preceding lines
have 24.

Note: readtable detected the following parameters:
'Delimiter', '\t', 'HeaderLines', 21, 'ReadVariableNames', true, 'Format', '%T%f%f%f%q%f%f%f%f%f%f%q%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f'
```

Here's what I've come up with as an alternative solution:

```
dataStartRow = 23;
numRows = length(readmatrix(filePath, 'NumHeaderLines',0));
dataEndRow = numRows - 8;

opts = detectImportOptions(filePath);
opts.DataLines = [dataStartRow, dataEndRow];
dataTable = readtable(filePath, opts);
```

This works but I have another file with a different number of footer rows and I don't know how to deal with this without hardcoding in the number of footer lines.

I've considered using `fgetl`, and reading lines in one by one to determine when to stop adding to the table, but that seems very inefficient.  How can I import this table with an unknown number of table lines and an unknown number of footer lines?

Comment: Don't conclude that something 'seems very inefficient' unless you've profiled or timed it and found that it's actually too slow for your requirements. However, what is the error you get from `readtable` if you don't specify `DataLines`? You might be able to do something by changing one or more of the [replacement rules](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.text.delimitedtextimportoptions.html?s_tid=doc_ta) in your `opts` object.

Comment: @nekomatic I've updated the question with the error given by `readtable`.

Comment: So I would try adding `opts.ImportErrorRule = 'omitrow';` after your `opts = detectImportOptions(filePath);` and before doing the `readtable`, which should avoid the need to specify `DataLines`. Let us know if that works.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  Could you please post an answer to the question so that I can mark it "Answered"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't conclude that something 'seems very inefficient' unless you've profiled or timed it and found that it's actually too slow for your requirements.

In this case though, you can change the action MATLAB takes in the event of an error, by setting this property of your [delimitedTextImportOptions object](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.text.delimitedtextimportoptions.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
opts = detectImportOptions(filePath);
opts.ImportErrorRule = 'omitrow'; # ignore any lines that don't match the detected pattern
dataTable = readtable(filePath, opts);
```

If you use this code regularly to read in new data, I'd consider doing some sort of validation on `dataTable` to make sure it is consistent with what you expect, just in case a new file causes `detectImportOptions` to give a different result for some reason. For example if you know that the number of columns and their format should always be the same, you could specify

```
opts.Format = '%T%f%f%f%q%f%f%f%f%f%f%q%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f';
```

and then check that the resulting table is not empty.